# What is the basic difference between mapping file generated by SQLMETAL and EDMGenerator?

Tags: .net, linq, orm

I am making use of sqlmetal tool to generate mapping file for my entities. Recently I came across the EDMGen tool, which also generates the same mapping file.

What is the difference between these 2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sql metal** generated file is used in Linq to SQL (ORM)

where

**EDMGen** tool generated file is used in EntityFramework (ORM).

Comment: But in both the cases, the context is used. And database tables are represented in class forms.

Comment: @Vijay Balkawade  - you can have look to http://www.osellus.com/blogs/2009/06/04/linq-to-sql-vs-entity-framework/ for details might help you